# How to use freemarker list with hashmap variable

Tags: freemarker

In Java I am using a

```
HashMap<String, String>
```

which is then available in my freemarker template.

I can access it like this

```
Time:${candidFieldsList["STD-TIME_Environmental_1"]}
```

This will extract the value for the key STD-TIME_Environmental_1 from my map, this works fine. Now I need to combine this with a list to reduce the redundant code.

I have a area in my template which need to be repeated 4 times

```
Time:${candidFieldsList["STD-TIME_Environmental_1"]}
```

The difference to the other parts are only the number, so i tried to use the list to solve this. But it did not work

```
<#list 1..4 as x>
Time:${candidFieldsList["STD-TIME_Environmental_"${x}]}
</#list>
```

Instead of returning the value for the key, it returns a parser exception or  the string of this expression.

```
freemarker.core.ParseException: Encountered "$" at line 4, column 50 in template.ftl.
```

Was expecting one of:
    "]" ...
    "." ...
    "[" ...
    "(" ...
    "?" ...
    "!" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `+` operator to concatenate the strings:

```
<#list 1..4 as x>
    Time:${candidFieldsList["STD-TIME_Environmental_" + x]}
</#list>
```

Comment: BTW, `"STD-TIME_Environmental_${x}"` works too, only the `${x}` has to be inside the string (not-anymore-)literal, unlike in the attempt of the OP.